# Sending data from ajax to python ( I work with odoo)

Tags: python, ajax, odoo

I'm trying to send data from ajax to python and It didn't works. It didn't accept any data in ajax . 
when I make :
 data:{"email",email),
It returns : 
index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'

XMl

js

```
function getRegions()
{ email=$('#email_conn').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/regions",
                    data:{"email",email),
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data.message);


                    },
                    error: function(data){

                    alert("Erreur");
                    }

                });
```

Python

```
@http.route('/regions', auth="public", website=True, type='http')
def index(self):
    result = {}
    data = cgi.FieldStorage()
    output = data.getvalue("email")
    result['a'] = output
    return json.dumps(result)
```

I don't know why it didn't accept data :( 
Your help please

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `**kwargs` argument to index method if you want to pass data (eg using POST) to it.

So your method should look like:

```
def index(self, **kwargs):
    # body of the method
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing data to Python using the wrong syntax.
replace data:{"email",email),
to
data:{"email",email},